# Python (Django) Get Response API Not working

Tags: python, django, api-design

My code is unable to POST data to Get Response: `Getting authentication errors on the headers (Response on terminal)`. Have spoken with GR and they can see the traffic but advising that the code is wrong.

Here is the POST code:

```
import requests
from django.db import models
from elissa.functions import get_async_web_response, get_async_web_response_no_decode 

def post_lead(self):
    data = '{ "name": "' + self.first_name + '", "email": "' + self.email + '", "campaign": { "campaignId": "xxxxx" }, "ipAddress": "' + self.ip + '",  }' 
    headers = {"X-Auth-Token": "api-key xxxxxxxxxxxx","Content-Type": "application/json"}
    get_async_web_response_no_decode("https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts", "POST", data=data, headers=headers)
    print "post lead data: " + data 
    headers = requests.post('https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts')
    print headers.content
    response = requests.get('https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts')
    print response.content
```

Here are the error logs:

```
This is the error i get back:{
"httpStatus": 400,
"code": 1021,
"codeDescription": "There is something wrong with your request headers",
"message": "Unsupported `ContentType` header.",
"moreInfo": "https://apidocs.getresponse.com/en/v3/errors/1021",
"context": {
    "sentHeaderValue": "",
    "supportedHeaderValues": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ]
},
"uuid": "edaa9637-2fb0-4933-9da6-f2b3bacfeaf2"
```

}
{
    "httpStatus": 401,
    "code": 1014,
    "codeDescription": "Problem during authentication process, check headers!",
    "message": "Unsupported authentication method",
    "moreInfo": "https://apidocs.getresponse.com/en/v3/errors/1014",
    "context": [],
    "uuid": "a0af5b3f-101e-41de-b6b8-bba310bd40ba"

Hope you can help, and please do let me know if you need further information.

Cheers

Comment: can you post the error log here?

Comment: Please post a proper MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the full traceback obtained with the MCVE.